# The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method in Flex

Tags: java, json, actionscript-3, apache-flex, httpservice

I have to call a method in Java from Flex which consumes JSON and saves info in DB. When I call it from JSP it accepts the input but when I call it from Flex application it gives me the error
"The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method"

Below is my sample code from Flex.

```
var p:Object = new Object();
p.firstName  = 'Mary';
p.lastName = 'Thomas';
p.gender = 'Female';

var httpServ:HttpService = new HttpService();
httpServ.url ="http://localhost/samplewebservice/myPerson/insert";
httpServ.useProxy = false;
httpServ.method = "POST"
httpServ.headers = {Accept: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
httpServ.contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
var jd:JSONEncoder = new JSONEncoder(p);
var s:String = jd.getString();
httpServ.send(s);
```

Please let me Know where it went wrong. Thanks in advance

My service Code

```
@POST
@Path("/insert")
@consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@RequestMapping(value = "/insert")
public void save(@RequestBody Person person)throws Exception{
   try{
          myservice.insert(person);
      }
   catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStacktrace();
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var httpServ:HttpService = new HttpService();
httpServ.url ="http://localhost/samplewebservice/myPerson/insert";
httpServ.method = "POST";

httpService.contentType="application/json";

var header:Object=new Object();
header["Accept"] = "application/json";
httpService.headers = header;    

var p:Object = new Object();
p.firstName  = 'Mary';
p.lastName = 'Thomas';
p.gender = 'Female';

var params:Object=JSON.encode(p);
httpService.send(params);
```

Comment: Hi Jileni . Thanks for the quick reply. I modified the code like urs. NOw it says "The request sent by the client is syntactically incorrect."

Comment: this is a request mapping error, can you post the service method ?

Comment: try : public void save(@RequestParam(value = "p") Person person)throws Exception{ ...}

Comment: Tried the above fix Still it says The request sent by the client was syntactically  incorrect